# How can I validate modal window in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to register the news in a modal, and I succeed but the problem is when I want to validate the errors in the same modal, I do not handle ajax very well.
I want to know which code to use with ajax to display errors?

This code is my code

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="z-index: 1300;">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Nueva Noticia</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {!! Form::open(['id' => 'form', 'files' => 'true']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Titulo') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Titulo de la Noticia..', 'riquired']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('content', 'Agrega tu Noticia') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control textarea-content']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen', 'Agrega tu Imagen') !!}
        {!! Form::file('photo', ['id' => 'photo'] ) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="button" id="Guardar" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Guardar</button>

    </div>


{!! Form::close() !!}

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

y mi controlador

```
public function store(NoticiaCreateRequest $request)
 {

//MANIPULACION DE IMAGENES
if ($request->file('photo')) {
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $name = '/imagen/noticias/Cm' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = public_path() . '/imagen/noticias/';
    $file->move($path, $name);
}

$datos = new Noticia();

$datos->title   = $request->title;
$datos->content = $request->content;
$datos->photo   = $name;
$datos->save();

Session::flash('save', 'Se ha creado Correctamente');

return redirect()->route('admin.noticias.index');

         }
```

y mi request

```
     public function rules()
   {
return [

    'title' =>  'min:8|max:65|required',
    'content' => 'min:20|required',
    'photo' => 'required',
];
```

}

I want something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt7CD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isoxX.png)

Comment: Use Iframe instead of modal.

Comment: Does not have any example to work with iframe

Comment: Even though you are not very familiar with AJAX, I would recommend it anyway. With Laravel its very easy to implement. Just try some code, and we will help you if issues occur.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit form through a modal, pass a 'hidden' input type with a value '1' and name 'fromModal' which indicates if the form was submitted from a modal. If there is a similar form which is not submitted via the modal, keep that 'hidden' input type value '0'.

So whenever, you get an error in validation ,the input type value will also be received in the old() function and you can access it by old('fromModal').

If this value is 1, you can show the Bootstrap modal with

```
$('#modal-CSS-Selector').modal('toggle');
```

To display the validation errors, like the one you mentioned in the image, please have at the [Laravel Documentation for Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation).